# ajax posting to wrong controller

Tags: ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to call action comment on snippets  controller but for some reason the ajax call invokes the index action on home controller.

Ajax call

```
$(".test").click(function (evt) {

    var urlData = $(this).attr("href");
    var url = urlData.split("?")[0];   //URL is /snippet/comment?comID=2
    var commentID= urlData.split("=")[1] //

    $.ajax({
        Url: url,
        type: 'Get',
        date: { comID: commentID},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Comments").html(data);
        }
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =    UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, `Url` should start with lowercase `u`. Also `date` should be `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { comID: commentID },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#Comments").html(data);
    }
});
```

By the way all the string splitting stuff's probably useless. Why don't you simply use the url of the anchor that you are AJAXifying:

```
$('.test').click(function (evt) {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Comments').html(data);
        }
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi Darin, Thanks for the quick answer works perfectly. I have 1 more quick question. The comment action of snippet controller returns a partial view which gets displayed onto a new page(Not injected into the div #comments) any idea why could this happen?

Comment: please ignore the problem in the comment above i have resolved it using Ajax.actionLink.